# Going through a text file line by line in vb 2005

Tags: vb.net, flat-file

So my program needs to go through a plain text file line by line essentially:

```
Read line 1:
Do commands
loop
Read line2:
Do Commands
loop
```

etc until its done with the entire file does anyone know any good coding examples for this, all the tutorials seem to show open and writing/reading textfiles but nothing on how to do it line by line.

Answer (score 6):

```
For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")
  ' Do Something'
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
Using f As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("somefile.txt")
    Using s As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(f)
        While Not s.EndOfStream
            Dim line As String = s.ReadLine

            'put you line processing code here

        End While
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: hmm getting syntax error on this one :( basically all coming up red when copied/pasted

Comment: I've tested it and it works.
You should put the above code inside a function.