# SSIS Script Task fails when working with large files on server but works fine locally

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I am using VB.Net language inside an SSIS Script Component which scrubs data.
(Visual Studio 2010)

Here is the code :

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim pk As New Package
    Dim file As New System.IO.StreamReader(Dts.Variables("User::str_SourcePath").Value.ToString())
    Dim data As String
    data = file.ReadToEnd()
    data = data.Replace("'", "")
    data = data.Replace(Chr(0), "")
    data = data.Replace(Chr(1), "")
    file.Close()
    Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Dts.Variables("User::str_SourcePath").Value.ToString(), False)
    writer.Write(data)
    writer.Flush()
    writer.Close()

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

This script task runs successfully when I run it locally even if there are very large files, but the package that is deployed fails on the server only when working with large files ie more than 100 MB.(SQL Server 2012)

Comment: File.ReadToEnd!?!? Try doing this in a loop and reading/writing 1 line at a time.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283156/going-through-a-text-file-line-by-line-in-vb-2005

Comment: What changes do i need to make in my code and where should i add for each line statement?

Comment: What is the error that it fails with?!?!?

Comment: I get a target invocation error when i run the deployed package on the server.

Comment: How are you running the package on the server? Double click? Firing up VS? Running as a SQL Agent Job? Command line invocation? Since this is a SSIS 2012 package, are you using the project deployment model (packages live in the SSISDB)?

Comment: I right click on my Package(Package Deployment Model) click build. Go to bin\deployment on my local machine. Copy the deployment folder on my local machine. From this point on everything happens on the server:::--->Paste in on the bin folder on the server and then double click the manifest file, deploy on sql server. Then I Connected to Integration Services on the server, MSDB->Packages->Right Click->Run Package. Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation. Script Task Failed.

Comment: Click on your Script task and set to disabled. Does the package run to completion then (assuming you start with a clean data file)?

Comment: Yes the package is a success when i disable the script task when i run with a clean file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a blog for the solution.
http://sqldeveloper9999.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/script-component-working-locally-but-not-on-sql-server/

Comment: Normally, I upvote self-answers, but you haven't actually answered the question - you just pointed us to the answer. Please include at least the gist of the answer from your blog post.

Comment: It wasn't really clear from your original post that when running on the server it was accessing a _remote_ file. 99% of the time (including this time) it's a dead giveaway that SQL Agent account is incorrect. So now I suggest that you copy the file locally before running your cleanup script to stop more bizarre errors occuring.

Answer (score 0):

Despite your lack of error message, I'm assuming you're throwing an out of memory error.

What are your options to resolve?

### Throw more hardware at the problem.

Ensure you are executing your package in 64 bit mode (which precludes the use of the JET/Excel driver). If you're still running out of RAM, either add more to the box or do *something* to free up memory prior to ETL running.

### Fix your code

Right now, your code is reading the entire content of the file into memory to start doing your replacements.

## Fix A

Strings are immutable which means every string you have is sitting in memory. My understanding then is that you don't have 1 copy of `data`, you have 4 distinct copies because of the operations you perform. If you used the StringBuilder class instead, then it should be kinder on your memory.

## Fix B

Read the data in chunks. Yes, it's more coding you are responsible for but since you can't throw more hardware at the problem, you have to quit doing the bad thing. A for each loop reading and writing the scrubbed line should suffice.

Comment: I get a target invocation error. I used the code by Steve(given the answer above)...This works fine too but only on the local machine, the deployed package still fails.

Answer (score 0):

You should read and write 1 line at a time, this is usually faster and it uses almost no memory.

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim pk As New Package
    Dim file As New System.IO.StreamReader(Dts.Variables("User::str_SourcePath").Value.ToString())
    'Must save it to a temp file since you cannot update the file you are reading.
    Dim sTempFile As String = "c:\temp\MyTemp.txt"
    If IO.File.Exists(sTempFile) Then IO.File.Delete(sTempFile)
    Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(sTempFile, False)
    Dim data As String
    While Not file.EndOfStream
        data = file.ReadLine
        data = data.Replace("'", "")
        data = data.Replace(Chr(0), "")
        data = data.Replace(Chr(1), "")

        writer.WriteLine(data)
    End While
    file.Close()
    writer.Flush()
    writer.Close()
    'Rename (move) your temp file to the original name
    If IO.File.Exists(Dts.Variables("User::str_SourcePath").Value.ToString()) Then IO.File.Delete(Dts.Variables("User::str_SourcePath").Value.ToString())
    IO.File.Move(sTempFile, Dts.Variables("User::str_SourcePath").Value.ToString())

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, this code works fine on the local machine, but i still get a target invocation error when i run the deployed package on the machine.

Comment: Interesting. Target invocation errors come from reflection functions. This tells me that `Dts.Variables("User::str_SourcePath")` is not the correct variable name. Check the variable name on your server, it is likely spelled wrong.

Comment: Double-check and triple check. According to everything I am finding, it has to be your variable name. Besides, that is the ONLY thing that is using reflection in this code. If this still is not it, can you provide full error?

Comment: I right click on my Package(Package Deployment Model) click build. Go to bin\deployment on my local machine. Copy the deployment folder on my local machine. From this point on everything happens on the server:::--->Paste in on the bin folder on the server and then double click the manifest file, deploy on sql server. Then I Connected to Integration Services on the server, MSDB->Packages->Right Click->Run Package. Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation. Script Task Failed.